# ffmpeg, crop, select, then uncrop for the output

Tags: ffmpeg, editing, crop

I would like to use ffmpeg to:

1. Crop image
2. Detect scene change on the cropped image
3. Output the whole scene (uncropped image.)

I know how to do 1. and 2. but not 3.

Here is my command line:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "movie.mp4" -vf "crop=130:250:220:50,select=gt(scene\,0.011)" -vsync vfr "movieThumb%%04d.png"
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Attie - that's not implemented.

Comment: This may be possible to do in a roundabout way. I'll check within a couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg.exe -i "movie.mp4" -filter_complex "[0]split=2[roi][full];[roi]crop=130:250:220:50,select=gt(scene\,0.011)[roi];[roi][full]scale2ref[roi][full];[roi][full]overlay=shortest=1" -vsync vfr "movieThumb%%04d.png"`

The video stream is split into two - on one instance, scene detection is performed. Then it is resized back to full size, and the 2nd instance is overlaid on the first one. Since overlay syncs by timestamp, the scene change frames are the ones selected by overlay for output.